# How to display data in arraylist from database on chart MPAndroidchart

Tags: java, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore, mpandroidchart

Im trying to display the data i have in firestore database to my chart, ive set up an trial data on firestore to use. im new to using mpchart and firestore so im confused on how to display the data on the piechart and linegraph

This is my code so far

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private PieChart pieChart;
    LineChart lineChart;
    LineData lineData;
    LineDataSet lineDataSet;
    ArrayList lineEntries;
    FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        pieChart = findViewById(R.id.piechartmain);
        setPieChart();
        loadPiechartData();

        lineChart = findViewById(R.id.linechart);
        lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        lineChart.setPinchZoom(true);

        getEntries();
        lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(lineEntries, "");
        lineData = new LineData(lineDataSet);
        lineChart.setData(lineData);
        lineData.setDrawValues(true);
        lineData.setValueTextSize(12f);
        lineData.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        lineDataSet.setColors(ColorTemplate.JOYFUL_COLORS);
        lineDataSet.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        lineDataSet.setValueTextSize(18f);
        lineChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);



    }

    private void getEntries() {
        lineEntries = new ArrayList<>();
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(1f, 0));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(2f, 1));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(3f, 2));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(4f, 3));
        lineEntries.add(new Entry(5f, 4));

    }

    private void setPieChart() {
        pieChart.setDrawHoleEnabled(true);
        pieChart.setUsePercentValues(true);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelTextSize(12);
        pieChart.setEntryLabelColor(Color.BLACK);
        pieChart.setCenterText("expenses");
        pieChart.setCenterTextSize(24);
        pieChart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);

        Legend l = pieChart.getLegend();
        l.setVerticalAlignment(Legend.LegendVerticalAlignment.TOP);
        l.setHorizontalAlignment(Legend.LegendHorizontalAlignment.RIGHT);
        l.setOrientation(Legend.LegendOrientation.VERTICAL);
        l.setDrawInside(false);
        l.setEnabled(true);
    }

    private void loadPiechartData() {


        ArrayList<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
        String label = "type";

        db.collection("Warranty")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                Log.d("TAG", document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });

        entries.add(new PieEntry(0.2f,"food"));
        entries.add(new PieEntry(0.15f,"elec"));
        entries.add(new PieEntry(0.20f,"school"));
        entries.add(new PieEntry(0.12f,"entertainment"));
        entries.add(new PieEntry(0.25f,"Gas"));

        ArrayList<Integer> colors = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int color: ColorTemplate.MATERIAL_COLORS){
            colors.add(color);
        }
        for (int color: ColorTemplate.VORDIPLOM_COLORS) {
            colors.add(color);
        }

        PieDataSet dataSet = new PieDataSet(entries, "monthly expense");
        dataSet.setColors(colors);

        PieData data = new PieData(dataSet);
        data.setDrawValues(true);
        data.setValueFormatter(new PercentFormatter(pieChart));
        data.setValueTextSize(12f);
        data.setValueTextColor(Color.BLACK);

        pieChart.setData(data);
        pieChart.invalidate();
        pieChart.animateY(1000, Easing.EaseInOutQuad);
    }

}

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my database
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlFjs.png)

im kinda lost on how to display data from firestore since i searched their query already,  though i cant display it on the chart. im new so please guide me, thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: You never do anything with the data you fetch inside `onComplete` with the query - you would need to add it to an array and set that on the chart (either inside `onComplete` or by calling a separate method from `onComplete` with the data you retrieved).

Comment: @AlexMamo thanks ill change it, there's nothing wrong with the code, i just dont know how to display the data i got after i get in from the firebase. i hope to know how to code it since i cant find a tutorial that explains how because im new to coding.

Comment: @TylerV oh okay thanks! can you please maybe show how to add that array, since ive tried adding it on the Arraylist<pieEntries> but it doesnt seem to work. i kinda get the i should put it in a new arraylist but i dont know how to code and place the data from the oncomplete to the arraylist.

Comment: You may find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o/70178210#70178210) useful for dealing with the async call too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to have an `ArrayList` full of `PieEntry` objects, then you have to iterate through the result, as you already do, and add those objects to the list:

```
    db.collection("Warranty")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        List<PieEntry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            PieEntry entry = document.toObject(PieEntry.class);
                            entries.add()entry;
                        }
                        //Do what you need to do with the list.
                    } else {
                        Log.d("TAG", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please also note that Firebase API is asynchronous. So you cannot simply use the `entries` list outside the callback.